# Unequal superpositions of energy eigenstates in two-state quantum systems?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, superposition, two-level-system

Two-state quantum systems in a superposition of energy eigenstates oscillate with time between the possible states. If both energy eigenstates contribute with the same amplitude, the oscillation is between definite state $ \uparrow $ and definite state $ \downarrow $:

$$ A_1^2 + A_2^2 = 1 $$
$$ \psi(\uparrow,t) =  A_1 \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot e^{ -i \cdot E_1 \cdot t / \hbar } + A_2 \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot e^{ -i \cdot E_2 \cdot t / \hbar } $$
$$ \psi(\downarrow,t) =  A_1 \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot e^{ -i \cdot E_1 \cdot t / \hbar } - A_2 \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot e^{ -i \cdot E_2 \cdot t / \hbar } $$
$$ |\psi(\uparrow,t)|^2 = \frac{1}{2} + A_1 \cdot A_2 \cdot \cos (t \cdot ( E_2 - E_1 ) / \hbar ) $$
$$ |\psi(\downarrow,t)|^2 = \frac{1}{2} - A_1 \cdot A_2 \cdot \cos (t \cdot ( E_2 - E_1 ) / \hbar ) $$

$ A_1 $ is the contribution of the eigenstate with energy $ E_1 $ and $ A_2 $ is the contribution of the eigenstate with energy $ E_2 $. $ A_1 $ and $ A_2 $ are assumed to be real in this calculation.

There seem to be solutions with unequal amplitudes $ A_1 $ and $ A_2 $ of the energy eigenstates where the oscillation of probabilities is reduced in amplitude and so never reaches the definite states. It seems that after measuring the state in such a system, the amplitudes of energy eigenstates need to be equal and the expectation value for the energy changed.

Yet I cannot find any mention of such solutions in theory or in nature. Have I made a mistake or are they prevented by some principle?

Edit: Maybe measuring the spin of an electron in a magnetic field along an arbitrary axis is the same as switching to an arbitrary basis? That might look like an unequal energy superposition in the new basis?

Comment: Perhaps you could provide some equations. It could make it easier to follow your thoughts.

Comment: @Jakob go to https://brunni.de/quantum_mechanics/  and search for "final description of the system". It's a work in progress - writing it up in this way seems to improve my understanding.

Comment: Note that questions should be self-contained; you should provide every necessary information in order to properly understand your question. This also improves the probability you will receive sophisticated answers.

Comment: @Jakob I've added my general equation for the probabilities to the question

Comment: I suggest using different labels for the energy states ($1$ and $2$) and for the superpositions (e.g., $\pm$ or $a,b$). Perhaps this already clarifies something...

Comment: @Vadim 1 and 2 are superpositions of energy eigenstates. I've replaced them with up and down arrows.

Comment: It is clearer now. Note also that amplitudes can be complex. Apart from that, there is nothing wrong about the amplitudes having different magnitudes - perhaps, you do not encounter it because of the particular context or the level of the books that you looked into. Also, there are no new phenomena with unequal amplitudes, so it is somewhat technical.

Comment: @Vadim yeah I was assuming there is no loss of generality by making them real. The phase of the amplitude represents different starting conditions. I don't think new behaviour will be seen with complex amplitudes.

Comment: Something’s not clear here. Where are your energy eigenstates and  what is $\psi(\uparrow,t)$ a superposition of? A superposition should be a sum of vectors (or functions), but at $t=0$ or any other $t$, you don’t have a such a sum: you have a sum of numbers.

Comment: Do you mean $\vert \uparrow,t\rangle=A_1\vert 1\rangle e^{-iE_1t/\hbar}+A_2\vert 2\rangle e^{-iE_2t/\hbar}$?  Your $\psi(\uparrow,t)$ isn’t normalized as currently written, and is not a sum of vectors in your space.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero As I understand the formalism, ψ(↑,t) is not supposed to be a vector but a complex number. The state vector has both ψ(↑,t) and ψ(↓,t) as elements.

Comment: @brunni states are vectors in some Hilbert space.  They can be made from complex combinations of basis vectors (*e.g.* eigenstates of $\hat H$).  Superpositions are (complex)  linear combinations of vectors.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero the vectors are there, they are just written in another form. Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation "Here, Ψ ( x , t ) is a wave function, a function that assigns a complex number to each point x at each time t". The Hilbert space here is two-dimensional so x can only take 2 values. Both values of the function form the vector.

Comment: where are your basis vectors?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I think (1,0) and (0,-1) for the state basis and (1/√2,1/√2) and (1/√2,-1/√2) for the energy basis.

Comment: @ZeroTheHeroThe notation to convert Ψ(x,t) to a bra/ket is <Ψ(t)| and |Ψ(t)>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain systems - like electron spin - can be described by a two-state system plus changes of basis. The change of basis corresponds to measurement of spin along a different direction in space and can look like an unbalanced superposition from the point of view of the new basis.

All possible states of a two-state system can be represented as points on the Bloch sphere and opposite points on that sphere always form a basis https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere